# Confused student ft. Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I'm one of the many fascinated programmers watching how **Machine Learning** can help the globe on various issues, given the power of the technology. I really want to get myself into ML and I've got fairly good amount of time to start and get to a point where I could choose what I want to do with ML. But as a beginner I'm really confused where to start in this sea of things it is offering. I'm also willing to complete a small abstract using my knowledge in ML. Any suggestions or experiences may help! Thank you.

Comment: This question is to broad for here, we are answering specific programmic question. Anyway, how about to start with an Introduction to ML? Book some course somewhere and get started...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a detailed link which will take you through various steps with reference to tutorials -  [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/learning-path-learn-machine-learning/)

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 1):

For beginners, I feel that this course is well-structured:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning

Then, you could try doing some small projects yourself and catch up the pace slowly.